# What is the "PGP Global Directory Verification Key"?

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, key-management, pgp

In the server keys of the MIT, there is several signatures from "PGP Global Directory Verification Key".

Example (from http://pgp.mit.edu/pks/lookup?op=vindex&search=0xB63024F96C73DA99):

```
sig  exp   CA57AD7C 2013-07-14 2013-07-28 __________ PGP Global Directory Verification Key
sig  exp   CA57AD7C 2013-10-10 2013-10-24 __________ PGP Global Directory Verification Key
sig  exp   CA57AD7C 2013-10-24 2013-11-07 __________ PGP Global Directory Verification Key
sig  exp   CA57AD7C 2014-03-04 2014-03-18 __________ PGP Global Directory Verification Key
sig  exp   CA57AD7C 2014-03-17 2014-03-31 __________ PGP Global Directory Verification Key
sig  exp   CA57AD7C 2014-05-02 2014-05-16 __________ PGP Global Directory Verification Key
sig  exp   CA57AD7C 2014-05-16 2014-05-30 __________ PGP Global Directory Verification Key
sig  exp   CA57AD7C 2014-06-25 2014-07-09 __________ PGP Global Directory Verification Key
```

What does it mean? And why they are all expired (if "exp" means "expire")?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### PGP Global Directory

The [PGP Global Directory](https://keyserver.pgp.com/vkd/GetWelcomeScreen.event) is a certification authority that validates that you have access to the mail address if you want it signed (but doesn't validate anything further than that).

In the end, it is a kind of yellow pages for mail addresses, you can look up keys in there, and with a given chance key owner and mail address owner actually are the same person, but do not trust in it (for example, man in the middle attacks on unencrypted server to server mail transmission would still be possible).

### Expired Certifications

Alongside being listed on their key server, certifications are issued. These expire after a very brief period of two weeks, but new ones are added after you validated the respective mail addresses again. As keys are removed after half a year and they send you a reminder e-mail to reverify your key, you will often find these certifications being issued twice a year.